# access an instance of ASIHTTP

Tags: iphone

I hope to access the instance of ASIHTTPRequest

```
{
ASIHTTPRequest *myRequest;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ASIHTTPRequest *myRequest;

//-----------------------------------

 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
 [request setTag:selectTag];

 myRequest=request;

 [request startAsynchronous];
```

if I force the request stoping work

I used the codes

```
        if (myRequest!=nil)
    {
        [myRequest cancel];

    }
```

but myRequest always returns 0x00000000

Welcome any comment

Comment: Try using this myRequest= [request retain]

Comment: have you allocated any memory to "myRequest"?

Comment: instead you can try - self. myRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]; and there after..if (self.myRequest!=nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to test if the request is already finished or canceled.

```
if (myRequest && ![myRequest isCancelled] && ![_request isFinished])
{
     [myRequest cancel];
     myRequest = nil;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this its work for me

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"]; 

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setPostValue:email forKey:@"email_id"];

    [request setPostValue:pasw forKey:@"user_password"];

    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request startAsynchronous];
```